# call a function in a hook

Tags: function, drupal, drupal-7, hook, drupal-modules

I have created  a custom module 'sample'.I have created 'user_login' hook.I want to call a function 'calltype' within user_login hook but the function is not called.Cookie is created If I write the callType function code after the line `$anivpopup = '1';` in user_login hook

```
function sample_user_login(&$edit, $account){
 $anivpopup = '1';
 callType();
}
function callType(){
 $anivpopup =1;
 if($anivpopup == '1'){
     setcookie('test', '2', time()+3600);  //cookie set for 1 hr
 }
}
```

Comment: ? Why aren't you sending `$anivpopup` to the function `callType()` ???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference: What is variable scope, which variables are accessible from where and what are "undefined variable" errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959576/reference-what-is-variable-scope-which-variables-are-accessible-from-where-and)

Comment: noo need to pass the value.check my updated post.just given a sample code

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
function sample_user_login(&$edit, $account){
  if(function_exists('callType'){
     callType();
  }else{
    die('Function callType does not declared');
  }
}
```

You must to know , drupal hook implementation is in cache so , on every modification made **you have to clear registry cache**

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
function sample_user_login(&$edit, $account){
 $anivpopup = '1';
 callType($anivpopup);
}

function callType($anivpopup){
 if($anivpopup == '1'){
     setcookie('test', '2', time()+3600);  //cookie set for 1 hr
 }
}
```

Hope this helps you.